# Удаление элемента

Tags: jquery, javascript

Здравствуйте. Подскажите код, как сделать, чтобы удалялся элемент с классом *tur*.  
Все перекопал, не нашел в Интернете.

Comment: $('.tur').remove();

Comment: http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8 - пункт удаление содержимого.

Comment: > Все перекопал, не нашел в Интернете.

Простите, а как вы вообще умудрились не найти такое?

Comment: Ну не знаю, как то не нашел

Answer (score 1):

Как один из вариантов.

```css
.tur {
 border: 1px solid #6495ed;
 margin: 5px;
 padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="tur">Элемент 0</div>
<div class="tur">Элемент 1</div>
<div class="tur">Элемент 2</div><br>

<input type="button" value="Удалить Элемент 1" onclick="document.getElementsByClassName('tur')[1].outerHTML = '';">
```